# Sharepoint page not opening folders in web parts

Tags: web-part

I have a web page that has a couple of document libraries as web parts. All the libraries has folders with documents in them. On the main page, I can not open any of the folders.  I can go directly to the library and the folders open fine.  The error I get when trying to open the folders from the main page is.

The "XsltListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Value does not fall within the expected range.

I even created a new web page and new libraries.  Still happens on the new page and library. Any Ideas?

I am on Sharepoint 2016 Standard edition on premise.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using OOTB library webpart? or have customized xsltlistviewwebpart ?

Comment: I created a list from a different page, opened that list in SPD to create a web part.  Added that list to the main page.  That seems to be breaking the folders from other web parts.  If I remove that new web part, the folders open fine.  If I add that list web part, I can't open the other folders.  Hope there is a fix for this.